# Appium - 'POST /element' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running

Tags: java, android-automation

I am trying to run an automated test in appium, what happens is that the app does get launched however fails to perform any action. Please see error below:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'POST /element' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details.

Comment: Share your test code in the question please.

Comment: `UiAutomator2` is for Android so the log is found in Android Studio's [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Answer (score 0):

When the driver is getting disconnected that error is displayed.
Adding this code helped me

```
 driver = DriverManager.getDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

See the configuration of the cache from the Gradle daemon or configure global .gradle/gradle.properties

Put this lines:

*org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8*

This solve the problem